# FFMPEG ERROR on streaming video generated from MediaRecorder API on RTMP url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ffmpeg, getusermedia, mediarecorder

Ref : https://www.mux.com/blog/the-state-of-going-live-from-a-browser

The above blog states my problem in detail and presented a solution also.
I am trying to implement the solution which is using socketio

Here is the description of the problem :

I want to capture the video and audio from the browser using

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
```

and i am using the

```
const options = {
    mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8",
};
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

to record the video chunk by chunk from the stream given by getusermedia and then using the socket io to send the video to the backend. Where I am using the ffmpeg to stream the chunks on rtmp url.

I am using the following ffmpeg commands :

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-i', 'pipe:0',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
    '-c:a', 'aac',
    '-ar', '44100',
    '-f', 'flv',
    rtmpurl
]);
```

And I am getting the following errors:

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4JEr.png)

[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lYXY.png)

[Error Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KVjO.png)

Can anyone help me how to fix this. I am new to FFmpeg.

Here is the complete frontend and Backend code :

```
Frontend (App.jsx) :
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  let video;

  useEffect(() => {
    video = document.getElementById("video");
  }, []);

  const socket = io("http://localhost:3050");
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected to server");
  });

  let stream;
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
    .then((strea) => {
      video.srcObject = strea;
      stream = strea;
      const options = {
        mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8",
      };
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      console.log(mediaRecorder);
      let chunks = [];

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
        console.log(e.data);
      };
      mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" });
        console.log("emitted");
        socket.emit("videoChunk", blob);
        chunks = [];
        // const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // const a = document.createElement('a');
        // a.href = videoURL;
        // a.download = 'video.mp4';
        // a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(videoURL);
      };
      mediaRecorder.start();
      setInterval(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.start();
      }, 2000);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error accessing camera:", error);
    });

  // Capture video after 10 seconds

  return (
    <>
      <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoPlay></video>
      <button id="captureButton">Capture</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Backend Code :

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }, maxhttpBufferSize: 1e8
  });

  const rtmpurl = 'rtmp://localhost/live/test';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');

    const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-i', 'pipe:0',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'veryfast',
        '-tune', 'zerolatency',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-ar', '44100',
        '-f', 'flv',
        rtmpurl
    ]);


    ffmpegProcess.stdin.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
    
    ffmpegProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    ffmpegProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });


    socket.on('videoChunk', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk)
        ffmpegProcess.stdin.write(chunk);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
        ffmpegProcess.stdin.end();
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3050;

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from /test route!');
});


server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```